# Set button background image change onClick without edit xml, cause button background always clicked issue in some circumstances

Tags: android, android-button

I have tried to change the onClick image of a button using this code in the listener

```
public void onClick(View v) {
   if(v==ButtonName)
   ButtonName.setImageResource(R.drawable.clicked_button_image);
   //action code                              

}
```

The image of the button in this way changes correctly, however if someone uses the *Back button* of Android device, the button appears with clicked image (because clearly is showed the last instance of the previous activity)

if I try to use the code:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
       if(v==ButtonName)
       ButtonName.setImageResource(R.drawable.clicked_button_image);
       ButtonName.setImageResource(R.drawable.unclicked_button_image);
       //action code                              

    }
```

The images of the button doesn't changes.

How could I solve this problem? (without edit the xml).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about changing back when you click on the back button?

```
@Override
public boolean onRestore()
{
    if(unclickedImageDisplayed)
    {
       ButtonName.setImageResource(R.drawable.unclicked_button_image);
    }

}
```

If you look at the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html), and the activity lifecycle, you can see that the method `on Restore` is called when you are coming back to an activity.

Maybe by having a private variable that you change when you change the background of your button, and by checking this boolean value for example, you can change the background of your button to give it his initial state, programmatically.

Comment: The button is in another class Activity so this code doesn't works because instanciates a new Button with the unclicked images and doesn't changes the button of the previous Activity.

Comment: So edit your problem to explain it better, you don't specify the button is not referenced in the actual class don't you?

Comment: So what about restoring the unclicked image nackground on the onRestore() event, or the onResume() event?

Comment: How could I solve the problem with  onRestore() event, or the onResume()? Could you give me more details editing your answer?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this effect try this:

you must create a new xml in your drawable folder: (I called button_action)

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/clicked_button_image" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/unclicked_button_image"/>
</selector>
```

in your layout:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/infobtncontact"
        style="@style/ButtonNormal"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_action"
        android:src="@drawable/unclicked_button_image" />
```

maybe have to restart eclipse to recognize the changes.

Excuse me for my horrible english!

Comment: It is specified without modifying the xml.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you explain why you want to use this method, you should really use a custom Button like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/clicked_button_image" /> <!-- pressed -->
  <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/focus_button_image" /> <!-- focused -->
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/unclicked_button_image"/> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```